# Jenkins windows slave No tty allocated failure

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I might have hit a roadblock in troubleshooting an issue with building a Jenkins job on a windows slave. I am not sure what needs to be done to fix the following issue? Here are the logs

```
Building remotely on Windows Slave (windows) in workspace
c:\Builds\workspace\windows-nuget-push
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:SDK-NewGen/sdk.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:NewGen/sdk.git
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:NewGen/sdk.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e1feb68bcc21e8801a5bcaf087bda5041370fbf7 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f e1feb68bcc21e8801a5bcaf087bda5041370fbf7
> C:\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-list e1feb68bcc21e8801a5bcaf087bda5041370fbf7 # timeout=10
[windows-nuget-push] $ sh -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson8489555376979916245.sh
      2 [main] sh 140924 tty_list::allocate_tty: No tty allocated
+ ./update-repo.sh
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson8489555376979916245.sh: ./update-repo.sh: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I think the failure is indicated by the following log message and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
2 [main] sh 140924 tty_list::allocate_tty: No tty allocated,
```

A quick google search pointed me to [this link](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_gitk_on_Cygwin_display_.22git_1316_tty_list::allocate:_No_tty_allocated.22.3F), but I am not able to resolve this issue by removing `tty` from the `CYGWIN` environmental variable.

It will be great if someone could shed light on the reason for this failure and steps to fix it

..and here is the shell command that the Jenkins build job would execute

```
./update-repo.sh
```